# sharepoint designer 2010 workflow how can I dectect field changes in a field updated by infopath rules

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Just like it says, turns out when you update a list or library field using an InfoPath rule, it doesn't notify the workflow the item was updated, so my workflow is just stopping. I have verified that the item has changed to Yes, from No.

Anyone know a way around this? Or am I being stupid and missing something easy here?

Comment: Well never mind, the problem seems to be my dumb ass not understanding how workflows work.

Comment: watch the language ;) and either post an answer, hence make a nice Q/A or just delete the question. As it is with your comment it's no use for future users. Thanks and have fun!